# When is CUDA/OpenGL interop thread safe?

Tags: opengl, cuda

I have two threads:

1) the first produces data to display (with CUDA) and uploads it to OpenGL texture using:

```
cudaGraphicsMapResources(TEX)
// Copy data to TEX
cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(TEX)
```

2) the second consumes the data and draws a textured rectangle

```
glBindTexture(TEX)
// glBegin() ... glEnd()
glBindTexture(0)
```

**Is this safe to do without any locking?**

---

`cudaGraphicsMapResources()` documentation says it will on one hand make sure that it be synchronized, but on the other hand that any OpenGL calls while resource is mapped yield undefined behavior.

Quoting [CUDA Graphics Interoperability Docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html):

- `This function provides the synchronization guarantee that any graphics calls issued before cudaGraphicsMapResources() will complete before any subsequent CUDA work issued in stream begins.`

  - So at the moment of calling cudaGraphicsMapResources() will wait for all pending OpenGL operations? But will they be blocked until cudaGraphicsUnmapResources()?
- `The graphics API from which resources were registered should not access any resources while they are mapped by CUDA.`

  - So if I call try to draw in-between map/unmap am I in trouble?

Comment: The latter text you quote only refers to the actual mapped resources. If you try and draw using CUDA mapped resources, expect it to fail. But other GL resources should be OK